# LVM: Can't remove lv after partitioning the disk

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have created a situation in my lab CentOS, but I do not know how to resolve it.

I created the pv, vg and lv in a disk without partitioning it, and after that I partitioned the disk, but then the pv, vg and lv vanished. Now I can not remove the lv from the machine, it shows up when i run `fdisk -l`, but not when running `lvs` or `lvdisplay`.

Any ideas on how to remove it without rebooting the system ?

[image: commands]

[image: df]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output - copy the actual text and [edit] your question to paste the text into it.

Comment: I can't read those screenshots. Text please.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't partition the disk after setting up LVM. Only creating a FS over LV can be done.